# Can i get a family consisting of a lot of relatives eg brothers and sister whom i dont have in this life in jannah?

Tags: quran, hadith, prophet-muhammad, allah, jannah

Assalamualaikum

It is said that we get whatever we wish for in jannah and also we can be with our family in jannah.in this life if i dont have a big family consisting of uncle aunties brithers and sisters will i be able to get a brother or sister in jannah if i wish to or a friend that i dont have here but i like to have one(its like someone who dont have a family in dunya but like to have a family in jannah bcz its said that couples who dont have children in dunya will have children in jannah)

Jazaka Allah khair